# Best practice for constantly checking a cookie for expiration?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using Vue with a Node.js backend to develop a web application with login feature.
Say I have a login cookie and I want to do something:

- 30 seconds before it expires
- After it expires

I also might have the condition where I have no guarantee that the cookie's expiration time stays the same unless I change it. I.e. I do not think I should set a callback to trigger (expiration - now) seconds as soon as I get the cookie.

I am aware of Vue's nextTick function. Would it be appropriate to check the expiration of a cookie in that callback? I am not sure if something else exists which would be a smarter way to perform HTML updates based on a time sensitive piece of data.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged

Comment: But the cookie might not change? It just has a date that says "I expire at this time."

Comment: Doesn't that remove the cookie?

Comment: Even if it does, I also want to do an action an amount of time before the cookie expires.

Comment: @TimMorris Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developing a similar application right now, using vuejs and node.js express backend.
I use JWT tokens, where I store the expiration date. If a user makes a request, the frontend checks if the token is expired. If it is expired, request a new token from the backend. To do that, I store not only the token, but also a refresh token. So if the expiration date is due, the client requests a new token and makes the request with that afterwards.

Comment: It's working pretty good for me. They both get stored in localStorage (might change that later). The token for authentification is the JWT token, the refresh token is just a random String, which is valid for a week. So if the JWT token expires, it gets a new one with the jwt token. If the refresh token expires too, user needs to log out again. The cool thing is that I can revoke these tokens, which is generally a problem with JWTs.

Answer (score 3):

Using [cookies.onChanged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged):

```js
browser.cookies.onChanged.addListener(({removed, cookie, cause}) => {
    if (removed && cause === "expired") {
        // Cookie expired
        console.log(cookie, "has expired")

        setTimeout(() => {
            // 30 seconds after cookie expired
            console.log(cookie, "was removed 30 seconds ago.")
        }, 30000)
    }
})
```

Comment: What if I want to trigger something 30 second before it expires? Would I just make a second cookie set to expire at that time?

Comment: You could check the cookies on page load and set a timeout for the milliseconds to cookie expiry minus 30000